# Filtering list of tables through IAM in DynamoDB Admin Interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I'm trying to filter the list of table names in the DynamoDB admin UI using IAM.

When I use this policy it shows all tables:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "XXXXXXX",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
        "dynamodb:ListTables"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I use this policy it shows nothing (just "Not Authorized" message):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "XXXXXXX",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
        "dynamodb:ListTables"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:table/table_to_show"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your policy.

As pointed out in the above comment the URN is wrong it should be starting with
`arn:aws:dynamodb:*`

Second `ListTables` operation in dynamoDB is not allowed to be accessed at resource level
Quote from [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/UsingIAMWithDDB.html#ARN_Format)

`You can use resource-level ARNs in IAM policies for all DynamoDB actions, with the exception of ListTables. The ListTables action returns the table names owned by the current account making the request for the current region; it is the only DynamoDB action that does not support resource-level ARN policies.`

So it you try any other operation it will pass like `DescribeTable`

Solution to this is that you should add a policy just for `ListTables` operation with `"Resource":["*"`]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was trying to prevent the user from seeing all of the table names, so based on that quote from the documentation, it doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to change the ARN of Dynamo DB table in this format.

*"Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/Books"*

[Using IAM to Control Access to DynamoDB Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/UsingIAMWithDDB.html#ARN_Format).

Another point: To list something in Admin console, you would need more permission than the Describe and list, since the list shows the attributes etc. Try adding all these (this will be effectively full read on specific table).

```
            "dynamodb:ListTables",
            "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:Scan"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the ARNs are in the correct format - they work fine for everything else. I've Xd out my details in the examples.

Comment: I am adding some more info in the above answer - give a try.